# Update tableview with regular time intervals in iphone

Tags: iphone

I have created  a sample application. It has fetched data from server for every 1 sec and updated the result in UITableView. I had already done. But it crashes my app rapidly. What I do is call NSTimer every sec.

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                         target:self 
                                       selector:@selector(MainLoop) 
                                       userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

In that timer function i have called NSThread function.

```
-(void)MainLoop
{
  if(isPreviousThreadFinished)
  {
    NSLog(@"Thread Opened");
    isPreviousThreadFinished = NO;
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(MainLoopThread) toTarget:self  withObject:nil];
  }
}



-(void)MainLoopThread
{

MainLoopPool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];

//Get data from the server

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(UpdateTable) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];


[MainLoopPool release];
}

-(void)UpdateTable
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    isPreviousThreadFinished = YES;
    NSLog(@"Thread closed");

}
```

It works fine. And reloads data correctly from the server. I stop NSTimer in `viewWillDisappear` method. When I go to previous page sometimes it crashes application. In console i have seen the error is given below,

```
bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0xb2aa410: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...
```

What is wrong with my code? Crashes appear randomly.

Comment: Are you calling UIKit in the "//Get data from the server" part? Check the documention for classes used in that block of code for whether they're safe to be used in threads other than the main thread.

Comment: What you are doing is starting a new thread and then in that thread, you are calling the main thread to perform some operation.Wouldn't it be conflicting the main thread's executions? I am not sure, but this may be the reason.

Comment: I fetch data from webservice call.(It's an http link).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I work on my application I discovered very good thing - **NSOperation**. It's thread safe. You can simply add you operations to the queue without fear to crash. There are a lot of tutorials about NSOperation

http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/03/04/iphone-coding-turbo-charging-your-apps-with-nsoperation/
http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/16/cocoa-tutorial-nsoperation-and-nsoperationqueue/

I strongly recommend you use NSOperation-s instead of threads in your project.